# How do I convert event callbacks to async tasks in C#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, callback

I'm working with a system that registers methods as event listeners.

A typical pseudocode example is something like this:

```cs
public class Foo {

   public void StartOperation(){
      EventSystem.Subscribe<EventFoo>(this, Handler);
      DoSomethingThatWillTriggerAnEvent();
   }   

   void Handler(EventFoo e)
   {
      // Handle the event
   }
}
```

I would like to be able to wrap this kind of event handling in an async task, so I could do something more like this.

```cs
EventFoo e = await DoSomethingThatWillTriggerAnEvent();
```

What's the best way to go about doing that?

Comment: You attach a handler for the event after you do the thing that will trigger the event? Isn't that "shutting the stable door after the horse has bolted"?

Comment: OK yeah, good point.  I'll edit that.